# How do i get multiple values from a popup window then insert it in the database

Tags: arrays, insert, popupwindow

im new here so could anyone help me. im trying to make a document tracking system and im having problems in getting multiple values from a popup window then inserting them in the database table so that the only people who could access those documents are those on the inserted list. can anyone help me please?? >_< newbie

Here is part of my code -- when i click it it selects from a listbox in a popupwindow.

```
    <html>
   <input id = 'input2' type="button" value="Select Route" onclick="SelectName()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    function SelectName() {
        popup = window.open("offices.php", "Popup", "width=500,height=500");
        popup.focus();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

here is the Popup_info--

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<html>
<head>
<title>Select offices</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"  type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function select(){
var str='';
for (i=0;i<s1.length;i++) { 
if(s1[i].selected){
str +=s1[i].value+ "  "; 
}
} 
document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML=str;
return true;
}
function select_all(){
var str='';
for (i=0;i<s1.length;i++) { 
s1[i].selected=true
{
str +=s1[i].value+ "  "; 
}
} 
document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML=str;
}
function deselect_all(){
var str='';
for (i=0;i<s1.length;i++) { 
s1[i].selected=false
{
str =""; 
}
} 
document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML=str;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
<center>
    <p> Select the Document Route.</p> 
    <p> Hold ctrl for multiple Selection.</p>
<?php include ('db.php');   
$data = mysql_query("select office from office_table");
echo "<select name = no_year id= s1 onChange='select()'; required multiple size= 10 value ='' width='200' style='width: 200px' > ";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    echo "<option> ".$row['office']."   
     </option>";

}
    echo "</select>";
?>
<div id='msg3' width = 300> <table ></table></div>
</body>

<br><br><br><br>
<input type='button' value='Select All' onclick='select_all();' id = 'input2'  />
<input type='button' value='Clear' onclick='deselect_all();' id = 'input2'  />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Set_select();" id = 'input2'  />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Set_select() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
            txtName.value = document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML;
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I'm just new on php and i want to insert the data i get here into the table specifically. i mean by each click its a separated data when inserted. please help.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. I have almost no idea what your doing based on what you've provided =/.

Comment: @Theodore Sorry Sir. im kinda new here. please help.

Comment: I'm still having trouble following what you're wanting to do,
but I believe it's this :
You want the user to select a "name" from a <select> input and then pull documents (from sql database?) based on what they've selected? Or do you want to take what they've selected and put it into a <table> ?

Comment: seems like it sir. This code is working. it selects multiple data and outputs them in String. what i want is to insert those data into a table. separately. so i can identify which user can access the document.